# Whole website in ajax in cakephp

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I want to make a website in cakephp framework.but the important thing is I have to develop whole website in ajax(No page refresh).
Although I have good experience of open sources magento,drupal etc.but I am new for the cakephp.I want to know ,what should I have take care for improving the efficiency of the website.
In My layout there is header section,right panel and footer section.
When a user clicks on header section right panel and some of middle content will reload. I want to know I should send a sing Ajax request or multiple Ajax request.
Please guide me or give some outline for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing special about ajax in CakePHP but you can define another layout and view for ajax responses than for a regular request.

If you want to return json or html is up to you. See [this section](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) of the book for json responses.

If you want to update two sections in one ajax call I think you'll have to return json that will contain two values you can access to make a difference between them and your server side code has to be written in a way that it knows that it should return section1 and section2. How you do that is up to you, there several ways.